# How can i export database on creating apk file?

Tags: android, database, apk

I got a problem with database. Im testing my application with Galaxy Note 10.1 (running Android 4.2.2). I wrote a simple application with database. On emulator it works fine. When i create a apk file and install to my Galaxy it cant find a database. and i check a directory from Android/data/package_name. But there are no name of my package directory. What i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

The default path for app database is `/data/data/<package_name>/databases/<database_name>`

Unless you have rooted the device (or working on an engineering build), you can not pull (export) the database from application's data folder.